# How to add Yii in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, yii, integrate

I have a big project in Zend and a small one in Yii.

Now I want to integrate Yii project in Zend project.

Is it possible or no ? And if it's possible are there any links, from where I can read and integrate my project. I've searched in google, but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do both: Include 3rd party libraries into Yii and use Yii in other projects. Please have a look at the official guide:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration

The main steps to integrate Yii e.g. in Zend are:

```
require_once('path/to/yii.php');
Yii::createWebApplication('path/to/config.php');
```